# global keyword not reflecting

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to print few commands, by calling via.., function: below is my code:

```
import re

new_acl_statement = ""

 cisco_commands = [
     "ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10",
     "ip access-list extended vlan19_in",
     new_acl_statement,   =====> # this is variable
     "exit",
     "ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10",
    "end"]


def check_acl_config():
    output = "90 permit ip host 1.1.1.1 host 2.2.2.2"
    if "2.2.2.2" in output:
        strip_output = re.split('\d+', output, 1)
        acl_statement = strip_output[1]
        seq_num = re.findall('[0-9]+', output)
        acl_seq_num = seq_num[0]
        int_acl_seq_num = int(acl_seq_num)
        int_acl_seq_num += 1
        str_int_acl_seq_num = str(int_acl_seq_num)
        global new_acl_statement                   ==========> # global keyword defined
        new_acl_statement = str_int_acl_seq_num + acl_statement

        return cisco_commands
    else:
        return "nothing"


send_command = check_acl_config()
print(send_command)
```

After executing above code, i've output like below:

```
['ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10', 'ip access-list extended vlan19_in', '', 'exit', 'ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10', 'end']
```

From output you can see, it just prints out statements which are from variable "cisco_commands". I've some logic inside "if" function and that one is not executing? I've defined **global keyword** for variable "new_acl_statement" why it's not reflected in my output?

expected output:

```
['ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10', 'ip access-list extended vlan19_in', '91 permit ip host 1.1.1.1 host 2.2.2.2', 'exit', 'ip access-list resequence vlan19_in 10 10', 'end']
```

can someone guide me where i'm going wrong?

Thanks & Regards,
Madhu

Comment: If you assign something to `new_acl_statement`, that’s not going to retroactively be included in the list! The list isn’t storing the variable by reference, it’s storing the value the variable had at the time you put it into the list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `cisco_commands` is defined before the assignment of `new_acl_statement` . Even though when you define the new value its not going to change in `cisco_commands` . Its better to update the `cisco_commands` after the new value is updated.

Comment: Thanks venkat for checking,
question:   Inside function i defined "Global" keyword for vairable "new_acl_statement".  may i know why new value will not affect in "cisco_commands"?

Comment: @madhuwill It has nothing to do with `global`. `a = None; b = [a]` Here `b` is now `[None]`, and nothing you do to `a` will change that. The list is not storing a reference to `a`, it's storing the value `a` had *at the time you put it into the list*.